# Tomcat service dies on startup

Tags: windows-server-2003, tomcat, windows-service, tomcat6

I have added the following arguments to the JVM options for a Tomcat Windows service:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
```

However, it now dies on startup. The most recent `jakarta_service` log file was empty, so I changed the log level to Debug in tomcat6w.exe and restarted it, but it just prints the command line arguments to the log file and then dies again. There was nothing in the other log files.

Comment: Run it manually on a console perhaps? There has to be some output somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran it manually as ETL suggested, and the problem turned out to be that the `jmxremote.password` file needs to have its permissions set to only be readable by its owner, which should be set to whichever user the service runs as.

Comment: Add the output of the console to your original post to make this Q/A more valuable to others who may search for the same thing.